# Resizing Partions with GParted

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, gparted

So here's the situation:

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Running `df -h` gives me the following partitions:

```
/dev/loop0    ,    29G,  9.3G,   19G,  33%, /

udev,            1.9G,  4.0K,  1.9G,   1%, /dev

tmpfs,           771M,  892K,  770M,   1%, /run

none,            5.0M,     0,  5.0M,   0%, /run/lock

none,            1.9G,   15M,  1.9G,   1%, /run/shm

/dev/sda2,       466G,   54G,  412G,  12%, /host
```

Would it be possible to use GParted to resize my 466GB Windows 7 partition into a 300GB Windows 7 partition and a 166GB partition for media that Ubuntu can graft on as a sub-tree, leaving my Ubuntu system partition the same size and without having to reinstall Windows, i.e. grab 166GB worth of free space from the windows partition and add it to Ubuntu? (The issue is that I bought my laptop used, so I don't have the install CD.)

If so, does GParted automatically graft the partition on, or will I have to mount it? And what of the file system journalling? Will I have to manually configure that?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Of course, I'll back everything up beforehand just in case. Thanks. Apologies in advance if this question has been answered or is a duplicate; my knowledge of *NIX file systems is at an all time low...

Comment: You do know you have a wubi install which is not a partition at all but a file inside the Windows NTFS partition. /host is the NTFS partition that wubi is in. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

Comment: Ah okay! Thanks a lot. So I guess I'll just have to uninstall it and install Ubuntu, then?

Answer (score 0):

First of all to resize the system partition you have to unmount the partition, therefore you can't do it directly on the system, but you have to use a live cd (or usb). The ubuntu live cd is fine, otherwise you can use something like http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php
Then you should make sure that the partitions to resize are adjacent.

The problem here is that you can't add anything to ubuntu partition since it does not exist because you probably used wuby (as said by oldfred)